# Upgrade iPad2 to previous iOS version (from 4 to 6, but not 7)

Tags: macos, itunes, upgrade, ipad, ios

I have an iPad2 with original iOS4.3.3, no jailbreak. Now there are several apps that require iOS 5 or above and I'm ready to upgrade. But I don't want to install yet the latest iOS7 (heard about some bugs, performance issues, etc.).

I backed up all the data and apps with iTunes (11.1) on Mac computer. But in iTunes I have only iOS7 as the option to upgrade. It's a pity I'm just a few weeks late, when this new os became available.

I've tried hard to google it, but all the links discusses just upgrade to iOS7.

Is there any way to upgrade to previous iOS6 now? Better without jailbreak, but if there will be no other choice I may consider ...

Comment: It is my understanding that unless you have the SHSH blobs for the version you'd want (if that makes no sense, then you don't have them).

Comment: I havent seen any issues with iOS 7 yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For security reasons, once a new update is released the old ones are no longer supported, so there is no way to upgrade to six or seven.

However, there is no issue upgrading to iOS 7, because the interface is slicker and prettier, and it utilizes the iPad's resources well.

Comment: What security reasons ?

Comment: Apple releases new security patches in every new version. If they allow upgrades to earlier versions, it will leave the user vulnerable to attacks.

Comment: Thanks, you convinced me to try iOS7. Anyway, that "security reasons" from Apple are pretty lame since they cannot force users with older iOS to upgrade. Well, only by releasing apps with restricted iOS support.

Comment: Well, iOS7 is indeed pretty good. Thanks again. The answer is accepted. An example that negative answer can be the right answer.

Comment: Thank you yuk, I appreciate it. Definitely look forward to answering any further questions that may arise after upgrading to iOS 7 :)